# Web page needs to be refreshed for YouTube video to autoplay - how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am using a Youtube video embed as a background for a website's homepage/landing page. I want it to autoplay whenever someone visits that web page, but there's a glitch. The video doesn't autoplay on the first web page visit, but if you refresh the page, the video will autoplay. How can I get the video to autoplay every single time? It happens for me on Chrome and Firefox, so may happen on other browsers too.

I am using the YouTube iFrame Player API for this: https://jsfiddle.net/Sidders/69teu8zv/2/

```
<div id="home-video-container">
<div id="home-video"></div></div>

<script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('home-video', {
      height: '1080',
      width: '1920',
      videoId: '6142uv27UuY',
      playerVars: {
        'autoplay': 1,
        'playsinline': 0,
        'autohide': 1,
        'controls': 0,
        'showinfo': 0,
        'rel': 0,
        'cc_load_policy': 0,
        'suggestedQuality': 'highres'
        },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(fadeVideo, 64000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function fadeVideo() {
        var video = document.getElementById("home-video-container");
        video.style.WebkitTransition = 'opacity 1s';
        video.style.MozTransition = 'opacity 1s';
        video.style.opacity = 0;
        video.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=0)';  // IE fallback
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Not a solution, but have you tried just embedding the video? That way YouTube handles everything for you..

Comment: I experiemented with the following code but unfortunately the video still needs to be reloaded before it autoplays :( `<iframe width="1920" height="1080" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6142uv27UuY?&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`